# Select Input Not Working for Producing Different Plots in R Shiny

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to create a map which will depend on the selected input with shiny. I went through all the examples but for some reason my code seems right to me but obviously its missing something as its not working. The ui seems to work fine because it produces the slidebars I want however its not making any maps with the depending input. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my data:

```
> datamap
         Country.code EVENTONE EVENTTWO EVENTTHREE
1  Bosnia and Herzegovina       11        1          5
2             South Korea        1        4          4
3             Philippines        1        5          6
4               Indonesia        1        6          8
5                Thailand        1        0          9
6                Mongolia        1        0          3
7      Russian Federation        1        0          4
8                 Ukraine        1        0          8
9                Slovenia        1        0          5
10               Mongolia        1        0          0
11               Pakistan        1        0          0
12             Bangladesh        1        0          0
```

And here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
shinyUI(fluidPage( 
  titlePanel(title="Events in the World"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
           selectInput("var", "Choose Event:",
                       choices=c("Event One" = "EVENTONE", 
                            "Event Two" = "EVENTTWO", 
                            "Event Three" = "EVENTTHREE"))
    ),

    # Create a spot for the barplot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("TheMap")  
        )
     )
    )
   )


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  datamap <- read.csv(".../Desktop/mapexcel1CSV.csv",             
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
    sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(datamap, joinCode='NAME',       
     nameJoinColumn='Country.code')


  output$TheMap <- renderPlot({
  mapPolys(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot= input$var
                        ,mapRegion="world",
                        missingCountryCol="dark grey", catMethod = 
                        "fixedWith", numCats=20, 
                        oceanCol="light blue")}

  )
 })

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I created a reproducible example with your code. The ui actually seems fine in responding to the input change. Plot changes whether Event one, two or three is selected. I had my ui and server code defined (ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(...)) and server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {...}))). I also added library(rworldmap) at top so the package is loaded in the environment next time the app is run.

Some function in your code is possibly being masked by another package in your environment (try restarting R session). You can also try reading the csv file outside the ui and server code. Lastly, maybe try saving the csv file as a rda and then load the rda (to test if this is a possible file reading issue).

See if this helps and follow up with further issues!

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked!! When I restarted R session and loaded only these packages everything worked fine. Thanks so much again!